# guzzlehttp/guzzle sends HTTP request before ->send()

Tags: php, rest, composer-php, guzzle, postmates

I'm trying to use Guzzle to consume a [RESTful API](https://postmates.com/developer/docs#testing). Reading the [Guzzle documentation](http://guzzle3.readthedocs.org/http-client/request.html#post-requests), I call methods like `get` and `post` to configure a request, then `send` to actually run an HTTP request.

```
$request = $client->post('http://httpbin.org/post', array(), array(
    'custom_field' => 'my custom value',
    'file_field'   => '@/path/to/file.xml'
));

$response = $request->send();
```

However in my case, it seems an HTTP request is being sent during the call to `post` without the fields. Here's my code

```
define('CUST_ID', 'blahblah');
define('API_KEY', 'verysecure');

// Construct the underlying Guzzle client
$oClient = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(
    ['base_url' =>
    ['http://api.postmates.com/{version}/', ['version' => 'v1']],
    'defaults' => [
        // HTTP Basic auth header, username is api key, password is blank
        'auth'    => [API_KEY, ''],
    ]]);
$oRq = $oClient->post(
    "customers/" . CUST_ID . "/delivery_quotes",
    [], 
    ['pickup_address'  => '232 E Manhattan Ave, Denver, CO 80203',
     'dropoff_address' => '4400 Midwest St, Denver, CO 80205']);
```

The request that goes out though (no POST params)

```
POST /v1/customers/blahblah/delivery_quotes HTTP/1.1
Host: api.postmates.com
Authorization: Basic verysecure==
User-Agent: Guzzle/5.2.0 curl/7.37.1 PHP/5.6.0
Content-Length: 0
```

and the response

```
HTTP/1.1 400 BAD REQUEST
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Fri, 13 Feb 2015 07:32:16 GMT
Server: nginx/1.1.19
Content-Length: 205
Connection: keep-alive

{"kind": "error", "code": "invalid_params", "params": {"dropoff_address": "This field is required.", "pickup_address": "This field is required."}, "message": "The parameters of your request were invalid."}
```

So it looks like I'm authenticating, but not passing any post parameters. I tried using the `setPostField` method to set the POST fields with no luck. As I said it seems in that case an HTTP request is being sent before call `setPostField`, in either case an HTTP request is sent before I call `send`.

I've tried guzzlehttp/guzzle 5.2.0 and 5.0.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wow, looks like I was looking at 2 pieces of documentation, one for [the newer `GuzzleHttp\Client`](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/clients.html), one for [the older `Guzzle\Http\Client`](http://guzzle3.readthedocs.org/http-client/request.html#). The big difference with the new library is you need to call `createRequest` if you want to defer invocation of the HTTP request.

Working code under the new library

```
define('CUST_ID', 'blahblah');
define('API_KEY', 'verysecure');

// Construct the underlying Guzzle client
$oClient = new GuzzleHttp\Client(
    ['base_url' =>
    ['http://api.postmates.com/{version}/', ['version' => 'v1']],
    'defaults' => [
        // HTTP Basic auth header, username is api key, password is blank
        'auth'    => [API_KEY, ''],
    ]]);

// Create the request
$oRq = $oClient->createRequest(
    'POST',
    "customers/" . CUST_ID . "/delivery_quotes",
    [ 'body' =>
        ['pickup_address'  => '232 E Manhattan Ave, Denver, CO 80203',
         'dropoff_address' => '4400 Midwest St, Denver, CO 80205']]);

// Send the request
$oRsp = $oClient->send($oRq);
```